# Android Interface Buttons hide the bottom of my application

Tags: android

I have no idea how to solve this. It displays well on the preview and when I run the last button is hidden by the interface. It also happens when I add the ScrollView - it's not that.

I also don't want to hide the Android's button interface.

Without ScrollView
[image]

With ScrollView
[image]

XML

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context="com.example.tiagosilva.amob_android.ContactUsFragment"
android:background="@color/AMOB_gray">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:weightSum="3">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="serif"
        android:text="AMOB Headquarters"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="serif"
        android:text="Rua Padre Domingos Joaquim Pereira,1249"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="serif"
        android:text="4760-563 Louro"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:background="@color/AMOB_gray"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="serif"
        android:text="Vila Nova de Famalicão, Portugal"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="serif"
        android:text="Phone: (+351) 252 330 900"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="serif"
        android:text="Fax: (+351) 252 376 887"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="serif"
        android:text="E-mail: comercial@amob.pt"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="serif"
        android:text="GPS: 41º 26'.16''N / 8º32'31.89''W"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/gps_amob"
        android:id="@+id/gps_map"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/btn_emailUs"
        android:background="@drawable/round_buttons"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Email us">
    </Button>

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/btn_callUs"
        android:background="@drawable/round_buttons_green"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Call Us">
    </Button>

</LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: The layout rule for a `vertical` `LinearLayout` is "stack everything vertically, one after the next, using their requested heights, padding, and margins".

You have 12 widgets inside of that `vertical` `LinearLayout`. All have a height of `wrap_content`. Some have margins. The `LinearLayout` itself has padding.

If the sum total of all of that is greater than the height of the screen, some of it will not fit on the screen. You can use a `ScrollView` to allow the user to scroll to see all of it. However, using a `ScrollView` does not cause everything to fit like magic.

Comment: It's not the scrollview.... I say it on the question....

Comment: I know that. I explained that in my comment. Your problem is that you have **too much stuff** for the available screen space.

Comment: but with scroll view it should should everything... but it doesnt

Comment: "but with scroll view it should should everything" -- that is not what `ScrollView` does.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use fill_parent instead of match_parent for your container height. Your phone will think it has to fill the whole screen. But that isn't neccesary because of your Android button (header) interface.

Comment: fill_parent where?

Comment: In your linear layout tag ?

Comment: Why you have a weightsum 3 ?

Comment: i dont know... i have no idea what Im doing

Comment: i used it to make the image smaller.

Comment: i would recommende to lose the weight tags... and set a minimum height to your graph (200px ?) and retry the scrollview

Comment: it worked but I have to leave a big space in the end. https://gyazo.com/d874db835e6064cdbdf0b6a4b14e51c1

Answer (score 0):

First of all `weightsum` that you are using in your `LinearLayout` is useless.
Now, Why you are not seeing the button in your mobile but in preview is because in your preview, you have hidden the `actionbar`. 
Now, if you want to show the button in the layout then there are two ways:-

1. You need to resize the views and make them smaller. (**Unreliable an Not Recommended**)
2. You need to out the views above your buttons in a `ScrollView`.
   To do it efficiently, give your scrollview `weight = 1` and your buttons as you have written in your above code.

`

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="20dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="serif"
                    android:text="AMOB Headquarters"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="serif"
                    android:text="Rua Padre Domingos Joaquim Pereira,1249"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView4"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/AMOB_gray"
                    android:fontFamily="serif"
                    android:text="4760-563 Louro"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView5"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="serif"
                    android:text="Vila Nova de Famalicão, Portugal"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView7"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="serif"
                    android:text="Phone: (+351) 252 330 900"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView8"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="serif"
                    android:text="Fax: (+351) 252 376 887"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView9"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="serif"
                    android:text="E-mail: comercial@amob.pt"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView6"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="serif"
                    android:text="GPS: 41º 26'.16''N / 8º32'31.89''W"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/gps_map"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:src="@drawable/gps_amob" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_emailUs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/round_buttons"
            android:text="Email us"></Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_callUs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/round_buttons_green"
            android:text="Call Us"></Button>
    </LinearLayout>
```

`

What i'm doing over here is, Adding a `Scrollview` and `two Buttons` in a `LinearLayout`.
`Scrollview` is given `android:layout_weight="1"`.
Now what happens is, the buttons will take the space they need and rest of the space will be covered by `ScrollView`.

Answer (score 0):

Put the Linear layout inside scroll view. Because every mobile has different screen sizes, its best practice to put it inside a scroll view.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context="com.example.tiagosilva.amob_android.ContactUsFragment"
android:background="@color/AMOB_gray">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:weightSum="3">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="serif"
        android:text="AMOB Headquarters"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="serif"
        android:text="Rua Padre Domingos Joaquim Pereira,1249"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="serif"
        android:text="4760-563 Louro"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:background="@color/AMOB_gray"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="serif"
        android:text="Vila Nova de Famalicão, Portugal"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="serif"
        android:text="Phone: (+351) 252 330 900"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="serif"
        android:text="Fax: (+351) 252 376 887"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="serif"
        android:text="E-mail: comercial@amob.pt"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="serif"
        android:text="GPS: 41º 26'.16''N / 8º32'31.89''W"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/gps_amob"
        android:id="@+id/gps_map"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/btn_emailUs"
        android:background="@drawable/round_buttons"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Email us">
    </Button>

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/btn_callUs"
        android:background="@drawable/round_buttons_green"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Call Us">
    </Button>

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</FrameLayout>
```

Something like this should work.
Hope this helps!..

Comment: he wants to show the bottom buttons all the time. Your layout will hide the buttons and make them scrollable. Check my answer.